# How does Border Thickness Affect the width of the Margin, Padding, or content of the UI Control?

Tags: xaml, uwp

How does `BorderThickness` Affect the width of the `Margin`, `Padding`, or content of the UI-Control?
See XAML below.

Why does `TextBox` FirstName/Lastname with widths 183+183 + fudge-factor = 400 Width of Vertical `StackPanel`?

Why does `TextBox` City/State/Zip widths 216+70+70 + fudge-factor = 400 Width of Vertical `StackPanel`?

How is Fudge-Factor Calculated?

```
<!-- This code aligns perfectly on my Windows 10... But, I had
     to fudge the widths in ways i don't understand fully
    in order to get it to look right... how does that work?-->
<Grid Background="OrangeRed">
    <StackPanel Width="400" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Black"
           BorderThickness="2" Background="AliceBlue" Padding="0,0,10,10">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBox Header="First Name" PlaceholderText="John" 
                 Width="183" Margin="10,10,0,0" />
            <TextBox Header="Last Name"  PlaceholderText="Smith" 
                 Width="183" Margin="10,10,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBox Header="Address1"  PlaceholderText="1 main st"  
                Margin="10,10,0,0" />
        <TextBox Header="Address2"  PlaceholderText="" 
                Margin="10,10,0,0" />

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Header="City"   PlaceholderText="Townville" 
                Width="216" Margin="10,10,0,0" />
            <TextBox Header="State"  PlaceholderText="XX" Width="70"
                Margin="10,10,0,0" />
            <TextBox Header="Zip"    PlaceholderText="12345" Width="70" 
                Margin="10,10,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>


    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I'm sure its simple, I'm just not understanding how to add up all the pieces on each line such that it addes up to the container width of 400: `Padding` + `Border` + content + `Margin`s for each component on a stackpanel line.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question was more tricky than I expected.

The `Width` property is used during the layout phase of creating the controls. It tells the container how much space the control wants to be able to display. The `BorderThickness` is **included** in the control width.

Let's calculate a bit. Your top `StackPanel` has width of `400`. It has border of `2` on each side. It has a right padding of `10`. That leaves us `386`. The First and Last name `TextBox` controls have each left margin of `10`. That is `386 - 10 - 10 = 366`. Now if we divide `366 / 2 = 183`.

As for the controls below - `400 - 4 - 10 - 10 * 3 = 356` which is equal to `216 + 70 + 70`.

That seems to be exactly what we needed and gives the values you got experimentally.

**But wait**:

[image: Border right]

Even though the calculations are exactly right the result is still a bit off on my device if you close in on the **right border** of Last Name field. What happens? Enter **scaling**.

My screen has a scaling of 150%. Because UWP is built with high pixel density screens in mind, all the values you use are ["effective pixels"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/design-and-ui-intro#effective-pixels-and-scaling) not actual pixels and the system automatically performs the necessary calculations to make everything fit. With scaling of 150% we have a problem however. Let's do `183 * 1.5 = 274.5`. That is exactly at a half of a pixel, and that is something we can't display. Now **OS is the one who does the fudging**! If I run the app and use the Live Property Editor, I can see the actual render width of the `TextBox` controls is not `183`, but `183.333`.

[image: Render width]

Now let's calculate `183.333 * 1.5 = 274.9995 ~ 275`. So the system "fudged" one more "actual" pixel to make it possible to display the control. Of course this broken our layout and caused that there is 1 pixel less space available for the right border of the second control (which is stretched to 275 actual pixels as well).

So how to avoid all these issues?

Because the scaling takes place, Microsoft recommends to **align everything to multiples of 4**, that will make your design align to a 4x4 grid and will be pleasing to eye. Also multiplication by `.5` factors will not cause issues. The borders are safe too, as they are `2` effective pixels wide - `2*.5 = 3`. Ideally then, you should make it a habit to use multiples of 4 for all width, margin and padding values throughout your app, which will ensure everything will look sharp, crisp and without visual oddities.

Just to confirm, when I change the margins to be 12 effective pixels, the First and Last name text boxes will now be 180 pixels wide and the layout will look just right.

Comment: Thank you! 
I had the same issue, and was fixed simple re-write code with all spacings multiple by 4 and explain this to ours designers.